# how to convert part of string to a value mentioned in a list

Tags: c#, string, list, linq

I have a list of strings and stringOutput as example:

```
readonly List<string> carMake = new List<string>
        {
            "Toyota",
            "Honda",
            "Audi",
            "Tesla"
        };

string myFunction()
{
    // do some processing...
     string stringOutput = CallGetLatestRecord();
    // the above returns "a:toyota:c"
    //Call another function after changing the string to "a:Toyota:c"

    //I am planning to use **stringOutput.Replace** 
    //but don't know how to get toyota or list items values dynamically 

   callFoo(stringOutput);
}
```

So this is what I want. If my:

- stringOutput contains **"a:toyota:c"**, I would like to update it to **"a:Toyota:c"** using carMake.
- stringOutput contains **"a:audi:c"**, I would like to update it to **"a:Audi:c"** using carMake.

How do I convert this using Linq ?

Also, note that at runtime I dont know if it is toyota or any string... so I want a generic solution using Linq

Comment: If any approach is okay, `"a:toyota:c".Replace("Toyota", "Toyota", StringComparison.CaseInsensitive)` would probably work... so do a fold with carMake and your input string. If there's structure to your string (e.g. colon-delimited) maybe leverage that to split, map, join.

Comment: What have you tried?  What exception did you get?

Comment: @ShaneRay I have tried following: stringOutput.Replace(carMake.Any(s=>s.Contains(stringOutput)))

Comment: @Warty thats what I am trying to do. But how do I get "Toyota" to send to my Replace function ?

Comment: the LINQ options for this seem quite ugly compared to simple loop and .Replace

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should help you get started...

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string stringOutput = "a:toyota:c";
readonly List<string> carMake = new List<string>
    {
        "Toyota",
        "Honda",
        "Audi",
        "Tesla"
    };

string pattern = @".+?:(.+?):.+?";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(stringOutput, pattern))
{
    if (carMake.Any(s=>s.Equals(m.Groups[1].Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    {
        stringOutput = stringOutput.Replace(m.Groups[1].Value, carMake.First(s=>s.Equals(m.Groups[1].Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(stringOutput);
```

Comment: The pattern can be simplified, but was not sure if a:carMake:c was just some example text, and the actual value would be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this;

```
string Process(string stringOutput)
        {
            foreach (string c in carMake)
            {
                int i = stringOutput.IndexOf(c.ToLower());
                if (i > -1)
                {
                    stringOutput=stringOutput.Replace(c.ToLower(), c);
                }
            }
            return stringOutput;
        }
```